# Split text based on delimiter and create a new row in SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience

I have a SharePoint list that tracks the Form result. If user selects > 1 item, the list will be shown as below.

[image: Originally]

Is it possible to generate 2 separate rows of information in SharePoint instead of showing them together as 1 long list? That would allow me to indicate different status for different request.

Comment: Are you storing the data using SharePoint default list forms or using Microsoft forms?

Comment: @GaneshSanap Thanks for your comments! I am storing this using the SharePoint default list forms

Comment: What is the data type of Qlikview column? Are you manually entering the value (array of strings) for this column? Also, saving single (default) form & creating multiple entries is not possible out of the box. You need to customize the forms.

Comment: @GaneshSanap I am not manually entering, the data are coming from a sharepoint form, where users can select multiple items under the same qn